# Making a dynamic menu in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a dynamic terminal menu that a user can select from in Powershell.  At this point I have the code to display the menu, but not how to store the correct value in a variable:

```
$ouCounter=1
Write-Host "`n Please Select OU"
foreach ($ouEntry in ((Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter '(name=*)' - 
SearchBase 'OU=Resources,DC=dept,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=tld' -SearchScope OneLevel).Name)){ 
Write-Host $("   "+$ouCounter+".`t"+$ouEntry) 
$ouCounter++ 
} 
[int]$menuSelection = Read-Host "`n Enter Option Number"
```

This will produce this:

```
 Please Select OU 

   1.   HR 
   2.   Accounting 
   3.   Manufacturing 
   4.   PR 
   5.   Executives 

 Enter Option Number:
```

Of course when I select `4` for example `$menuSelection` returns `4` and not `PR`.

And since I don't know what the content of the list will be, because new AD Organizational Units can be added at any time, I'm not sure how to make this work.

I'd also like to figure out how to add some logic that it would only except the numbers in the first column, as in if I entered `6` it would tell me to try again until it got a number that was listed.  But, again that number will change with the amount of OUs present.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to generate a variable number of items in a menu. [*grin*] since i have no access to the AD stuff, i used my local groups.

```
$LocalGroupList = Get-LocalGroup -Name 'a*', 'h*', 'p*', 'u*'

foreach ($MenuItem in $LocalGroupList)
    {
    '{0} - {1}' -f ($LocalGroupList.IndexOf($MenuItem) + 1), $MenuItem.Name
    }

$Choice = ''
while ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Choice))
    {
    Write-Host
    $Choice = Read-Host 'Please choose an item by number '
    if ($Choice -notin 1..$LocalGroupList.Count)
        {
        [console]::Beep(1000, 300)
        Write-Warning ''
        Write-Warning ('    Your choice [ {0} ] is not valid.' -f $Choice)
        Write-Warning ('        The valid choices are 1 thru {0}.' -f $LocalGroupList.Count)
        Write-Warning '        Please try again ...'
        pause

        $Choice = ''
        }
    }

''
'You chose {0}' -f $LocalGroupList[$Choice - 1]
```

output ...

```
1 - Administrators
2 - HomeUsers
3 - Homonymic_Tuu
4 - Performance Log Users
5 - Performance Monitor Users
6 - Power Users
7 - Users

Please choose an item by number : 44
WARNING: 
WARNING:     Your choice [ 44 ] is not valid.
WARNING:         The valid choices are 1 thru 7.
WARNING:         Please try again ...
Press Enter to continue...: 

Please choose an item by number : 2

You chose HomeUsers
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just doing this...

```
Clear-Host

$ouCounter = 1
$MenuArray = @()

Write-Host "`n Please Select OU"

$DomainName = ($env:USERDNSDOMAIN).split('.')[0]
$Tld = ($env:USERDNSDOMAIN).split('.')[1]


foreach ($ouEntry in ((Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter '(name=*)' -SearchBase "DC=$DomainName,DC=$Tld" -SearchScope OneLevel).Name))
{ 
    $("   "+$ouCounter+".`t"+$ouEntry) 
    $ouCounter++ 
    $MenuArray += ,$ouEntry
}

do
{ [int]$menuSelection = Read-Host "`n Enter Option Number" }
until ([int]$menuSelection -le $ouCounter -1)

$MenuArray[$menuSelection -1]


# Results

 Please Select OU
   1.   Domain Controllers
   2.   EnterpriseServiceAccounts
   ...
   8.   FCI Server Security Groups

 Enter Option Number: 9

 Enter Option Number: 10

 Enter Option Number: 11

 Enter Option Number: 12

 Enter Option Number: 1
Domain Controllers
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer  https://www.business.com/articles/powershell-interactive-menu/

```
function Menu
{
     cls

     Write-Host "================ UNIT====="
     Write-Host "HR"
     Write-Host "Account"
     Write-Host "=PR="
     Write-Host "EXIT"
}

#Loop

do
{
     Menu
     #
       $Value = Read-Host "UNIT selection"
     switch ($Value)
     {
           'HR' {

                Write-Host "Human resource"
                #Execute the Command 
           } 'Account'

                { 

                #Execute command
           } 'PR' {

                #EXECUTE Command
                echo "test pr"
           } 'q' {
           cls
                return
           }
     }
     Sleep 2
     pause
}
until ($input -eq 'q')
```

Execution :

================ UNIT=====
HR
Account
=PR=
EXIT
UNIT selection: HR
Human resource
Press Enter to continue...: