# Using powershell to list AD users and making an interactive menu to remove specific user

Tags: powershell

so what i want to do is use powershell to list all ADusers into a basic interactive menu so that a specific user can be chosen and removed.

This is what I got so far, and this all users and allows me to select a specific one. But the `Remove-ADUser -identity $ouEntry` (on line: 18) runs right after I start the script and selects all the users for removal before I can select a specific one. I need it to run after i select an option, and with the correct user. I have been looking into a switch menu, but with poor results since I cant embed the ForEach properly.

Appreciate all help. I'm also open to alternate solutions

```
Clear-Host

$ouCounter = 1
$MenuArray = @()

$DomainName = ($env:USERDNSDOMAIN).split('.')[0]
$Tld = ($env:USERDNSDOMAIN).split('.')[1]

Write-Host "`nChoose the user you want to delete"



foreach ($ouEntry in ((Get-ADUser -SearchBase "DC=$DomainName,DC=$Tld" -Filter *).name))
{ 
    $("   "+$ouCounter+".`t"+$ouEntry) 
    $ouCounter++ 
    $MenuArray +=  $ouEntry + " was removed"
    $MenuArray += Remove-ADUser -identity $ouEntry
}

do
{ [int]$menuSelection = Read-Host "`n Enter Option Number"}
until ([int]$menuSelection -le $ouCounter -1)

$MenuArray[ $menuSelection-1]
```

Output

```
Choose the user you want to delete
   1.   Administrator
   2.   Guest
   3.   user1
   4.   user2
   5.   user3
   6.   user4
   7.   user5
   8.   user6
   9.   Jon Snow

 Enter Option Number:
```

Previous reference: [Making a dynamic menu in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55152044/making-a-dynamic-menu-in-powershell)

Comment: this >>> `$MenuArray += Remove-ADUser -identity $ouEntry` <<< is in your menu `foreach ($ouEntry` block. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider doing this in a Windows Forms GUI, so the list to choose from can have a scrollbar.
Having said that, the code you have now writes the entry on screen as menu item and **immediately** removes that user.

Below code first gets the users in an array once and creates a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) object from that.
The reason for using a List object is because with that it is easy to remove an item (unlike with using an array).

```
$DomainName = ($env:USERDNSDOMAIN).Split('.')[0]
$Tld = ($env:USERDNSDOMAIN).Split('.')[1]

# get an array of users in the given OU, sorted on the Name property
$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "DC=$DomainName,DC=$Tld" -Filter * | Sort-Object Name

# store them in a List object for easy removal
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
$list.AddRange($users)

# now start an endless loop for the menu handling
while ($true) { 
    Clear-Host
    # loop through the users list and build the menu
    Write-Host "`r`nChoose the user you want to delete.  Press Q to quit." -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $index = 1
    $list | ForEach-Object { "    {0}.`t{1}" -f $index++, $_.Name }

    $menuSelection = Read-Host "`r`nEnter Option Number."
    # if the user presses 'Q', exit the loop
    if ($menuSelection -eq 'Q') { break }

    # here remove the chosen user if a valid input was given
    if ([int]::TryParse($menuSelection, [ref]$index)) {
        if ($index -gt 0 -and $index -le $list.Count) {
            $userToDelete = $list[$index - 1]
            Write-Host "Removing user $($userToDelete.Name)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
            Remove-ADUser -Identity $userToDelete.DistinguishedName
            # remove the user from the list
            $list.RemoveAt($index - 1)
        }
    }
    # add a little pause and start over again
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes, perfect. It was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!